# How to run the nestjs application after add a command using nest-commander?

Tags: nestjs, nest-commander

I am trying to use [nest-commander](https://nest-commander.jaymcdoniel.dev/) in my Nestjs application, but I don’t really understand how it would work when executing my command. I created the command as the documentation says and added it in the main.ts.

```
(...)
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  const globalPrefix = 'api';

  (...)

  await CommandFactory.run(CommandModule);

  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  await app.listen(port);
  Logger.log(
    ` Application is running on: http://localhost:${port}/${globalPrefix}`
  );
}

bootstrap();
```

Now when I build the application and try to run it with node it tells me:

```
node ../../dist/apps/ns-backend/main.js
Usage: main [options] [command].
```

How does this library really work? How can I run my application normally after adding a command?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a `CommandFactory` and `NestFactory` in the same bootstrap function. Your `CommandFactory` should essentially be treated as a separate application, or at the very least a separately ran process

Comment: Can you help me with an example? I tried to create a separate file like main.ts, but when I build the application it only creates main.js.

Comment: [This repo](https://github.com/jmcdo29/unteris) uses separate applications for the cli and server, just as an example